# Where did the cantina and fishing boats come from?

Tags: crystal-fairy

In *Crystal Fairy*, the group finds a secluded spot to cook their cactus. All the shots during their arrival paint the area as being completely deserted and private. However, the next day we see that there are fishing boats right next to their tents and a cantina nearby. What gives? Were there earlier sweep-shots of the area that indicated that they were there?

Answer (score 1):

Their beach adventures seem to be taking place just a few hundred yards from a small village.

Based on the presence of fishing boats in the subsequent scene, I'd go so far as to hazard that it's a *fishing* village.

[image]